# CSS : dynamic position/margin based on sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I am trying to make stack of cards like effect using css.  I want position card based on its preceding card. Is there a way I can write some sort of equations in CSS. I can achieve this using jquery , but I want to know if I can do that in css.  no of cards are going to be dynamic in this case.

[image: these are cards. and they are going to be dynamic]

```
.card{ position:relative;left10px;} // this didnt work

    /*html*/
   <div id="uno-game">
        <div id="pot">
        </div>   
        <div id="my-cards">
            <ul>
                <li class="green card"><div class="card-inner">3</div></li>
                <li class="red card"><div class="card-inner">3</div></li>
                <li class="green card"><div class="card-inner">3</div></li>
                <li class="blue card"><div class="card-inner">3</div></li>
                <li class="yellow card"><div class="card-inner">3</div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    /*css*/
    #uno-game{
        height: 500px;
        width: 800px;
        background: green;
        border: 5px solid #000000;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: 100px;
    }
    #pot{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: darkgreen;
        margin: auto;
        border: 3px solid darkolivegreen;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
    #my-cards{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 5px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .card{
        display: block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 75px;
        color: brown;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .card:hover{
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .card-inner{
        height: 49%;
        width: 54%;
        background: wheat;
        border-radius: 40px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        padding-left: 23px;
        padding-top: 6px;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .green{
        background: rgb(101, 156, 16);
    }
    .red{
        background: orangered;
    }
    .blue{
        background: skyblue;
    }
    .yellow{
        background: yellow;
    }
```

Comment: I hope you actually tried `left:10px` instead of `left10px`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
.card + .card {
    margin-left:-70px;
}
```

Comment: perfect. I dont know css can be write like this.

Comment: One of the best explanation about CSS selectors! http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 4):

You can float the cards to left.

```
.card{
    float: left;
    margin-right: -5px; //you can change it according to your needs
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Would have really confused the OP when it didn't work.

Comment: Wow man. Worked like charm.

however that margin should be negative value to have stalk effect. please edit that to some negative value likt margin-right:-10px;

Comment: Glad to help. Well, I didn't know what effect you wanted, and that's why I left the comment that it cant be changed.